# get order id of a particular item on sort

Tags: mysql

Let's suppose we have a table with the fallowing values introduced in this particular order: 10, 11, 7, 5, 17, 147, 555.

If I were to try to find out where 11 for example was situated if I would have ordered the table ascending I would see that the index is 4.

However for large amounts of data I would not like to get the whole table and sort it in php beacuse that would be stupid.

What I want to know is if mysql can return the index of a value in an ordered query without querying all the values.

Thank you!

**UPDATE #1**

The query that I wanted looks like this (thanks to bluefeet):

```
SELECT rownum FROM (
SELECT col1, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
FROM yourtable,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) table1
ORDER BY col1) table2
WHERE col1=11
```

and you can test it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a21c8/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have a `rownum` per se but you can simulate it the following way:

```
SELECT col1, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
FROM yourtable,
(SELECT @rownum:=0) r
ORDER BY col1
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a21c8/1)

Using this you can determine the `rownumber` which might give you want you need.

If you then want a specific `rownumber` you can wrap this in a subquery:

```
select *
from 
(
  SELECT col1, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum
  FROM yourtable,
  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  ORDER BY col1
) x
where rownum = 6
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a21c8/13)

Comment: Thank you for this! In this paradigm how do I get only the value "6" for the table value "147" supposing I would like to know his place in the ordered table.

Comment: @mugur please see my edit, you can use a `WHERE` to then specify the `rownum` to return.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out finally that I could create nested derived tables :) as you can see in the update 1

Comment: @mugur glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

MySql doesn't have a special feature for this (that I know of), but you could use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html) to calculate the result. Still you are going to have to go through a lot of the data to compute the index, so on large datasets this will be expensive.